# change a process name from the outside

Tags: java, c++, linux, process

I am looking for a way to change the name of a (java) process name from another one.

Just to be clear, I have a process named "kuku" and another c++ process named "lolo", inside the "lolo" process I want to change the name of the  "kuku" process.

Is this possible?

Comment: From userspace, the answer is NO. That would be a huge security hole. If you want to write a kernel module, then you can do whatever you want.  It might help if you explain what you want to do and more important, why.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to restart the process with the name you want.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, how would he go about doing that?